# Email notification detailing cell change in specific column with corresponding value also provided

Tags: google-apps-script, spreadsheet

I have no experience writing GAS or javascript code, so I was hoping someone on this board can help me out with this request

I've been trying to create a script that will notify a specific email address when changes or additions are made to cells in column 'L' of my spreadsheet. Column B, however, contains the corresponding name to which the data in column L is relevant to. Therefore, I would like the body of the email notification to state that the 'company' (from the list in Column B) has had a figure input against it (from column L), as well as a link to the spreadsheet itself.

e.g. "Google" [cell B4] has been assigned the following ID "7601" [cell L4]

https://docs.google.com/a/company.co.uk/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AnpeVHKZr72qdFRoTWdK

Many thanks,
Simon

Answer (score 0):

Have you started at least so that contributors can help you with codes. They can not provide you full fledged solution.

If not, you may get familiar with apps script and start writing and then post your problem to with codes.
Or simply you may hire someone to do it.

Apps Script Resources:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles

https://sites.google.com/site/appsscripttutorial/

Comment: Apologies, I have been trying for a couple of days to get this right, but I haven't got far at all. The other elements of my request are nice to have, but my main trouble is restricting the trigger to only changes within column L. Is this something someone can help with?


function Email() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var value = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange().getValue().toString();
    MailApp.sendEmail("email@email.com", "Spreadsheet Updated!",
        "The spreadsheet has been updated" + "\n\n" + ss.getUrl());
  } 

Thank you, Simon

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment above, you may follow this approach.

```
//Check if the active column is L
var activeCellColumn = ss.getActiveSheet().getActiveCell().getColumn();
if( activeCellColumn == 12){
//do other task
}
```